# How to get result of one to one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-8, one-to-one

I'm using Laravel 8 to make a basic online ordering system.

And in this project, every order is submitted within a user of the user who has signed in.

[image]

So there is a **One To One** relationship between `users` table and `orders` table.

Therefore, I have added these to the Models:

`Order.php`:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
```

`User.php`:

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
```

Now in order to get the result of the table for showing the user name of the person who had ordered, I coded this at the Controller:

```
public function awaiting()
    {
        $orders = Order::with('user')->where('user_id', '!=', NULL)->latest()->paginate(20);
        return view('admin.orders.awaiting', compact('orders'));
    }
```

Then at the Blade:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $order->user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->dimensions }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->color }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->material }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->title }}</td>
    <th scope="row">{{ ++$menuCounter }}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But this is wrong because it searching for `order_id` at `users` table (which does not exist).

So the question is, how can I show the user name of the user who has ordered based on the `user_id` stored in `orders` table.

**UPDATE #1**:

`Orders` Migration:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('material');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('dimensions');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

`Users` Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->tinyInteger('adm')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking `null` you can use `whereHas`.Try changing.

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->whereHas('user')->latest()->paginate(20);
```

Your relationship is wrong so

**Order.php:**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

**User.php:**

```
public function order()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Order::class);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion but still searching for `order_id` at `users` table and shows this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.order_id' in 'where clause'`